# Split two columns in sql into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in following format

```
 ID      Loss        Sum
--------------------------
 1     146276293.1    1
 1     175538865.5    2
 1     146276293.1    3
```

I want SQL script to return me

```
   ID      Sum1         Sum2         Sum3
   --------------------------------------------------- 
   1     146276293.1  175538865.5   146276293.1
```

Comment: looks like you shouldl create a `pivot` select

Comment: Look into `dynamic pivot`.

Comment: Case statements or pivot would work if sum is limited to 3 groups if variable in number then dynamic pivot.

Comment: Instead of dynamic pivots I prefer to use a dynamic cross tab. The syntax is less obtuse to me. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple example does what you're trying to do. PIVOT is a great tool. Also research UNPIVOT when attempting the opposite.

```
select *
from (  
        select 1 id, 100 num, 'Sum1' col
        union select 1, 200, 'Sum2'
        union select 1, 300, 'Sum3' ) x
pivot 
(sum(num) for col in (Sum1, Sum2, Sum3)) p
```